# Update the Kernel Density as the new data comes in

Tags: scikit-learn, scipy, statsmodels, probability-density, kernel-density

How to incrementally update the parameters characterizing the kernel density estimator(KDE) fit to the old data with new data coming in periodically?

I have got a KDE fitted to the data. Say it is Gaussian characterized by mu and sigma. Now I've a new batch of data I want to use to adjust and update these parameters for a new KDE distribution. I am using Python Sklearn, Scipy and considering Statsmodels for this purpose.

If you have any suggestions or questions please let me know.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do this in scikit-learn, and I don't have much experience in the specified packages. However, I believe that such an implementation will not be easy. But take a look at [this](https://github.com/thaines/helit/wiki/kde_inc), and [it's code](https://github.com/thaines/helit/tree/master/kde_inc).

Comment: @QusaiAlothman Thanks for the links. Please let me know if you come across more resources related to my problem.